# Cannot change ssh port on High Sierra

Tags: macos, ssh

As subject: I cannot edit the file ssh.plist which is located in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons.  I want to change the sshd port.

I tried to use 'information' in the finder and unlock it.  This didn't work.    I tried:

As root, I tried..

```
macos:LaunchDaemons root# pwd && chown $USER ssh.plist 
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons
chown: ssh.plist: Operation not permitted
```

I also tried to cp the file to my own Desktop, edit it *in situ* and cp it back.

```
macos:LaunchDaemons root# pwd && cp /Users/darren/Desktop/ssh.plist .
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons
cp: ./ssh.plist: Operation not permitted
```

I did this before - a while back.  I think it was maybe the one before Sierra, but I don't recall the 'code name' of that release.

Has Apple locked this file down definitively?

Comment: Hi Darren, I was revising open questions and you may want to upvote/mark my answer as accepted, since, from your feedback, I understand it solved your issue. Marking a question as solved also helps others who have a similar issue, as it shows your question has the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 30):

> Has Apple locked this file [`/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`] down definitively?

Yes, they have, you need to disable SIP ([System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)), but note that editing `ssh.plist` is not the only option to change the SSH server port, there are other ways to achieve the same result.

---

***Edit**: macOS 11 Big Sur and later add [strong cryptographic protections](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secd698747c9/web) to system content, which seems to make the first proposed solution (modifying `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`) not feasible. Thank you to [Jo Liss](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/24654/jo-liss) and [Carl](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/63255/carl) for their feedback in the comments below!*

---

**There are (at least) 4 ways to change the port `sshd` listens on**:

1. Modifying `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`:

- **Pros**: cleanest way to configure `sshd`, `sshd` started with System Preferences>Sharing>Remote Login listens on new port.
- **Cons**: convoluted setup (requires two restarts and [disabling/re-enabling SIP](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016462-CH5-SW1)).
- **Use case**: definitive change of `sshd` port.

2. Creating a new plist `/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh2.plist`:

- **Pros**: dual operation of `sshd` listening on standard and new port.
- **Cons**: CLI-only method to start `sshd` on the new port.
- **Use case**: `sshd` must listen on both the standard port and the additional port.

3. Modifying "ssh" entries in `/etc/services`:

- **Pros**: simplest method, no need to deal with SIP, `sshd` started with System Preferences>Sharing>Remote Login listens on new port.
- **Cons**: side effect: `ssh` defaults to new port when connecting to remote server (there's a workaround for that).
- **Use case**: temporary port change or testing `sshd` running on a different port.

4. Redirecting port 22 to new port with packet filter:

- **Pros**: no need to deal with SIP, `sshd` started with System Preferences>Sharing>Remote Login *seems* to listen on new port.
- **Cons**: somewhat non-transparent (`sshd` configuration is untouched but `sshd` listens on another/additional port) and confusing (firewall status in System Preferences not reliable), tiny side effect (remote client thinks it is connecting to port 22 (through env variables `SSH_CLIENT` and `SSH_CONNECTION`)).
- **Use case**: definitive or temporary change of the `sshd` port, `sshd` must listen on both the standard port and the additional port.

Let's take a closer look at them. (When choosing the new port, make sure it is not used by another service by running `sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep <your port>`.)

---

**1. Modifying `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`**

This is the method you tried, let me describe it here for completion:

1. Restart your Mac and hold down <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> immediately after your Mac begins to restart to enter [macOS Recovery](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016462-CH5-SW1).
2. Select Utilities>Terminal from the menu bar.
3. Type `csrutil disable` to disable SIP.
4. Select Apple menu>Restart.
5. Log in, edit `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` and modify the Listeners section. For example, to change the port to `2222`:

[image]

6. Restart your Mac and hold down <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> immediately after your Mac begins to restart to enter macOS Recovery.
7. Select Utilities>Terminal from the menu bar.
8. Type `csrutil enable` to enable SIP and restart.

**SSH server will now listen on the new port and you can start `sshd` as usual through System Preferences>Sharing>Remote Login.**

---

**2. Creating a new plist `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh2.plist`**

This method is nicely described in this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/313618/32815), which basically says:

1. Copy `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` to `/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh2.plist` to create a new `sshd` startup script.
2. Modify the label in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh2.plist` to differenciate the new startup script from the built-in one, for example by appending a number "2":

   ```
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.openssh.sshd2</string>
   ```
3. Modify the port in the Listeners section as in the previous method. For example, to change the port to 2222:

   ```
    <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
       <key>Listeners</key>
       <dict>
          <key>SockServiceName</key>
          <string>2222</string>
          <key>Bonjour</key>
          <array>
              <string>ssh</string>
              <string>sftp-ssh</string>
          </array>
       </dict>
    </dict>
   ```
4. Start `sshd` on the new port:

   sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh2.plist

(To stop it, run `sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh2.plist`)

**The SSH server will now listen on the new port. You can still use System Preferences>Sharing>Remote Login to start another instance of the SSH server that listens on the standard port (22/tcp)**. `launchd` will listen on both ports:

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n
launchd     1           root   42u  IPv6 0x9df385961b132cdf      0t0    TCP *:2222 (LISTEN)
launchd     1           root   44u  IPv4 0x9df385961c81db1f      0t0    TCP *:2222 (LISTEN)
launchd     1           root   45u  IPv6 0x9df385961b132cdf      0t0    TCP *:2222 (LISTEN)
launchd     1           root   47u  IPv4 0x9df385961c81db1f      0t0    TCP *:2222 (LISTEN)
launchd     1           root   48u  IPv6 0x9df385961b133e1f      0t0    TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
launchd     1           root   49u  IPv4 0x9df385961b22d51f      0t0    TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
launchd     1           root   50u  IPv6 0x9df385961b133e1f      0t0    TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
launchd     1           root   51u  IPv4 0x9df385961b22d51f      0t0    TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
```

---

**3. Modifying "ssh" entries in `/etc/services`**

To change the `sshd` port with this method, proceed as follows:

1. Edit `/etc/services`, look for these entries:

   ```
    ssh  22/udp  # SSH Remote Login Protocol
    ssh  22/tcp  # SSH Remote Login Protocol
   ```

and replace port 22 with a port of your choosing.

**You can enable SSH with System Preferences>Sharing>Remote Login and `sshd` will listen on the new port.**

Why does this work? If you take a look at the Listeners section of the `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` file, you will see that `sshd` is configured to listen on the port assigned to the service named *ssh* in `/etc/services`:

```
<key>Sockets</key>
<dict>
    <key>Listeners</key>
    <dict>
        <key>SockServiceName</key>
        <string>ssh</string>
(...)
</dict>
```

**This is undoubtedly the simplest method, but it has a drawback: the SSH client will expect remote SSH servers to listen on the new port** (instead of port 22) (thanks to [jcaron](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335324/cannot-change-ssh-port-on-high-sierra/335329#comment432783_335329) for the hint). That is, `ssh` reads `/etc/services` to find out which the default SSH port is.

Fortunately there is an **easy solution** for this: uncomment `Port 22` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (see `man ssh_config` for more information).

---

**4. Redirecting port 22 to new port with packet filter**

The method uses the macOS packet filter (PF) to redirect all requests received at port 22 to the new `sshd` port (thanks to [Andrew Morton](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335324/cannot-change-ssh-port-on-high-sierra/335329#comment432679_335329) for the idea):

1. Create a new anchor file `/etc/pf.anchors/sshd` with contents (replace `2222` with a port of your choosing):

   ```
    rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port = 2222 -> 127.0.0.1 port 22
    # If you want `sshd` to listen on port 22 too, comment out the line below
    block drop in quick proto tcp from any to any port = 22
   ```
2. Add the "sshd" anchor rules by editing `/etc/pf.conf` (the order is relevant!):

   ```
    scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
    nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
    rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
    # Load sshd redirect rule
    rdr-anchor "sshd"
    dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
    anchor "com.apple/*"
    # Load other sshd rules
    anchor "sshd"
    load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
    # Tell PF where to find the sshd anchor
    load anchor "sshd" from "/etc/pf.anchors/sshd"
   ```
3. Enable and reload the packet filter:

   ```
    sudo pfctl -F all -ef /etc/pf.conf
   ```

(To disable it, run `sudo pfctl -d`.)

Note that:

- the macOS firewall (System Preferences>Security & Privacy>Firewall) is under the hood the packet filter, so that **when you disable the packet filter on the command line, you are also disabling the firewall, even if the Preferences Panel doesn't reflect the change.**
- **SSH clients will think they are connecting to port 22** through the `SSH_CLIENT` and `SSH_CONNECTION` env variables.

---

**Editing `sshd_config` doesn't work**

Users running `sshd` on other operating systems may be tempted to edit the SSH daemon configuration file, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. In macOS, however, **editing the `Port` directive in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` won't achieve the desired result**.

Comment: Would it make more sense to use the firewall to translate the port number? Especially as /etc/services is meant to be the IANA-assigned port numbers: [Non standard ssh port: should I edit /etc/services?](https://serverfault.com/q/761810/109573)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, I like your idea and I agree, modifying `/etc/services` feels like a hack. But as someone who has dealt with the packet filter (PF) in the past, I see editing `/etc/services` as the simplest and less error-prone solution. Unfortunately, `ssh.plist` doesn't support the Port directive defined in `sshd_config`, which is in my opinion the right way to configure the `sshd` port (that was the first thing I tried, and was baffled when I noticed it didn't work).

Comment: Does [Port Forwarding on macOS Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254777/300750) also apply to High Sierra?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, I guess so.

Comment: Didn't try it, but wouldn't that affect the default port for outgoing ssh connections?

Comment: @jcaron Outgoing SSH connections use an ephemeral port unrelated to the `sshd` port.

Comment: I mean the port being connected **to**. Don't know if `ssh` uses a hardwired default of 22, a default setting in `ssh_config`, or if it looks up the `ssh` service.

Comment: @jcaron I guess you mean `sshd` and `sshd_config` instead of `ssh` and `ssh_config`, you are asking about the SSH server, right? (sorry if I'm being pedantic, but words matter). To your question: after modifying `/etc/services/`, the port being connected to is always 2222, that is, all communication with the SSH server goes through port 2222. The reason is that, in macOS, `sshd` runs in inetd mode (`-i` option), and the "ssh" entry in `/etc/services` takes effect. When not run in inetd mode, `sshd` defaults to port 22, unless Port/ListenAdress are set to a different value in `sshd_config`.

Comment: @jaume, no, I actually mean `ssh`, the client. If it looks up the `ssh` service rather than use a hardcoded 22, then modifying `/etc/services` would also affect outgoing ssh connections (the default remote port the client would connect to). Not saying it’s actually the case (haven’t tried), just wondering.

Comment: @jcaron Now I understand what you mean, very good question, yes, I tested it and the SSH client reads the value of the "ssh" entry in `/etc/services` and tries to connect to port 2222 (or whatever port is defined in there). That is, `/etc/services` not only changes the behavior of `sshd`, but also of `ssh`. I didn't expect that, I will edit the answer and point that out (with a workaround).

Comment: I'd recommend copying ssh.plist into /Library/LaunchDaemons, changing the filename, label, and port, and loading that as a separate service. See [this page at codedmemes.com](https://codedmemes.com/lib/changing-ssh-port-mac-os-x/) for details.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks, I appreciate your comment, I saw the solution you mention yesterday here on Ask Different, see klanomath's answer at apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307940/…. There are several ways to change the SSH server port, some are simple but unelegant, some are flexible but complex. I've been thinking quite a bit about this question, I was planning on expanding my answer, and I will definitely mention the method you propose.

Comment: Confirmed #1 works on Mojave

Comment: im considering installing a 3rd party ssh server at this stage.

Comment: I've just tested (1) and after rebooting the sshd service couldn't start. I used the same synthax

Comment: Great post. However, I just tried the first method and couldn't accomplish the task because the file was still read-only even though `csrutil` was disabled; double checked. I get Apple's security concerns but the Mac is the Mac, leave it alone and have power users do what they want.

Comment: @CanSürmeli That's weird, the plist should be writable for root: `-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  1034 Aug 25  2019 /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`. Have you tried editing it as root? (you can either `sudo` to root first: `sudo su -` or edit it like this (replace `vi` with your favorite command-line editor): `sudo vi /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`).

Comment: @jaume Actually, I haven't tried with becoming `root` altogether first. Just initiated the `vim` with `sudo`. Can also try that but disabling `csrutil` first really sucks. Boooo Apple! But thanks.

Comment: On M1 with Monterey (maybe also Big Sur), the root filesystem is mounted readonly, so you cannot normally edit `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` even with system integrity protection disabled. I tried [entering recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl82829c17/12.0/mac/12.0#mchl5abfbb29), in the recovery terminal mounting the main partition read-write (`mount -uw "/Volumes/Macintosh HD"`), and then editing `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`, but the changes seem to have gotten reverted, possibly because I re-enabled SIP. Any ideas?

Comment: @JoLiss From what you explain, it seems Monterey rolls backs changes when you re-enable SIP, but since I'm still on Big Sur and can't test it. I'd recommend that you create a plist file in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` with your desired configuration, disable the built-in one: `sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` and enable yours with `sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/<your plist file>`

Comment: Possibly connected to comment by @JoLiss above: From other answers and Apple Docs [1], it seems that for Big Sur and later, `/System/` volume is _sealed_ <-> checksum-ed. If editing it, at next reboot changes will be reverted or system refuse to boot. Not sure if that is correct though?

[1]: https://superuser.com/questions/1771166/cant-edit-readonly-file-even-when-root-and-without-system-integrity-protection, https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secd698747c9/web

Comment: After struggeling with various solutions with this for a few years, I ended up configuring my router with a port forward to translate an external high-numbered port to internal port 22. The hackers on the internet may slam my port 22 as much as they want, contributing to the heat death of the universe at most. My macOS is left untouched and understands all ssh traffic to happen on port 22. This was the perfect solution for me, however, it requires a configureable external router/firewall. Also, occasional direct internet connections with the mac exposes port 22 if not actively disabled.